# Stacked chart in ggvis, rcharts for continuous data

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, ggvis

Below is a subset of the data I have.

```
Abby    John       Mike             Date
4.0       6         3               03-30
3.2       5         1               03-31
4.0       6         3               04-01
4.1       8         2               04-02
6.0       6         1               04-03
```

Am trying to plot a stacked/grouped bar chart with date on the x axis and all the users data on the Y (for a particular date 3 grouped bars on the Y axis indicating Abby, John and Mike's data). I tried using the 
Rcharts library example at: http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/index.html

But unlike the one used there, my data is continuous and not a factor. Is there anyway I can do this using ggvis or rCharts? I have only used these 2 plotting libraries as yet.

Appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts` in `RCharts`to do what you want. Note that you would probably need to manipulate the data a bit...

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rCharts)

# Prepare data
x <- data.frame(USPersonalExpenditure)
colnames(x) <- substr(colnames(x), 2, 5)
Names <- rownames(x)
Dates <- colnames(x)
colnames(x) <- Names
rownames(x) <- Dates

# Create chart
a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column")
a$title(text = "US Personal Expenditure")
a$xAxis(categories = rownames(x))
a$plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
a$yAxis(title = list(text = "Billions of dollars"))
a$data(x)
a
```

[image]